# NameAlreadyBoundException using JNDI

Tags: java, weblogic, jndi, jdeveloper

I created a session bean with this code:

```
package ejb2;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.SessionContext;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless(name = "TestEJB", mappedName = "EJB2-Project1-TestEJB")
public class TestEJBBean implements TestEJB, TestEJBLocal {
    @Resource
    SessionContext sessionContext;

    public TestEJBBean() {
    }

    public String getHello(String who_welcome) {
        return "Hello " + who_welcome;
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's almost a default code (except getHello method). Besides this bean I have a client:

```
package ejb2;

import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.naming.CommunicationException;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class TestEJBClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            final Context context = getInitialContext();
            TestEJB testEJB = (TestEJB) context.lookup("EJB2-Project1-TestEJB#ejb2.TestEJB");
            System.out.println(testEJB.getHello("Student"));
        } catch (CommunicationException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getClass().getName());
            System.out.println(ex.getRootCause().getLocalizedMessage());
            System.out.println("\n*** A CommunicationException was raised.  This typically\n*** occurs when the target WebLogic server is not running.\n");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static Context getInitialContext() throws NamingException {
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        // WebLogic Server 10.x/12.x connection details
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://localhost:7101");
        return new InitialContext(env);
    }
}
```

First time it worked like a charm. But then I created another bean:

```
package ejb2;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.SessionContext;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

@Stateless(name = "ClientEJB", mappedName = "EJB2-Project1-ClientEJB")
public class ClientEJBBean implements ClientEJB, ClientEJBLocal {
    @Resource
    SessionContext sessionContext;
    TestEJB testEJB;

    public ClientEJBBean() {
        try {
            final Context context = new InitialContext();
            testEJB = (TestEJB) context.lookup("EJB2-Project1-TestEJB#ejb2.TestEJB");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getHelloFromBean(String who) {
        return testEJB.getHello(who);
    }
}
```

And now beans aren't working. I get an error like this:

weblogic.application.ModuleException: Unable to bind Business Interface to the JNDI name: EJB2Project1WebApp_warClientEJB_Home, throw exception javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: [EJB:011224]Unable to bind the interface ejb2.ClientEJB to ClientEJB. Another EJB has already bound an interface to that name.; remaining name 'EJB2-Project1-ClientEJB#ejb2'. NestedException Message is :[EJB:011224]Unable to bind the interface ejb2.ClientEJB to ClientEJB. Another EJB has already bound an interface to that name.

What's the problem with these codes?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see you try to deploy two stateless EJBs with the same JNDI name
Try to undeploy the current application , check the JNDI tree from Admin Console 
and make sure the tree does not have the JNDI name you see as duplicate.

Comment: I checked my JNDI Tree. It doesn't contain any duplicated names.